# getNthRoots function wrong answers

Tags: c++, c

So i have a function

```
 Vector getNthRoots(double a, double b, double c, int n)
{
    Vector v;
    int i;
    v.length = 0;
    double m, a2, b2, c2;
    if (n % 2 == 0)
    {
        a2 = a;
        b2 = b;
        c2 = c;
        if (a<0)
            a2 = a*(-1);
        if (b<0)
            b2 = b*(-1);
        if (c<0)
            c2 = c*(-1);
        m = floor(pow(max(a2, b2, c2),1/n));
        for (i = 1; i <= m; i++)
        if (pow(i, n) >= min(a2, b2, c2) && pow(i, n) <= max(a2, b2, c2))
        {
            v.values[v.length] = i;
            v.length++;
            v.values[v.length] = (-1)*i;
            v.length++;
        }
        return v;
    }
    else {
        for (i = ceil(pow(min(a, b, c),1/n)); i <= floor(pow(max(a, b, c),1/n)); i++)
        if (pow(i, n) >= min(a, b, c) && pow(i, n) <= max(a, b, c))
        {
            v.values[v.length] = i;
            v.length++;
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

This function is supposed to give you the numbers at power n (number^n) which are in the interval of min(a,b,c) and max(a,b,c);

Other functions/headers

```
double max(double a, double b, double c)
{
    if (a >= b && a >= c)
        return a;
    if (b >= a && b >= c)
        return b;
    if (c >= a && c >= b)
        return c;
    return a;
}

double min(double a, double b, double c)
{
    if (a <= b && a <= c)
        return a;
    if (b <= a && b <= c)
        return b;
    if (c <= a && c <= b)
        return c;
    return a;
}

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

#define MAX_ARRAY_LENGTH 100

struct Vector
{
    unsigned int length;
    int values[MAX_ARRAY_LENGTH];
};
```

It seems i can`t receive the good answer . For example

for getNthRoots(32,15,37,5) it should return a vector [2] because 2^5 =32 which belongs to interval [15,37] but i don`t receive anything
or getNthRoots(32,1,7,5) it should return a vector [1,2] but i only receive 1 as answer

I am guessing here is the problem `for (i = ceil(pow(min(a, b, c),1/n)); i <= floor(pow(max(a, b, c),1/n)); i++)`but i don`t know how i could fix it

Answer (score 0):

1/n evaluates to 0, because it is evaluated as an integer expression. Try replacing all the "1/n"s with "1.0/n"s.

Take care to handle the case where n is 0.